# Find $\lim_{(x,y)\in S} \frac{x^2+ay^2}{x^2+by^2}$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ for specified $S$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Find $$\lim_{\stackrel{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{(x,y)\in S}} \frac{x^2+ay^2}{x^2+by^2}$$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ and

1. $S=S_1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid |y| < c|x|^p\}$ with $c > 0, p > 1$
2. $S=S_2=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid |y| < |x|\}$.

Here's my attempt by changing to polar coordinate.

$$x = r\cos \theta,\quad y = r\sin \theta$$.

So $$
\begin{align*}
f(x,y) = \frac{x^2+ay^2}{x^2+by^2} &= \frac{r^2(\cos^2\theta+a\sin^2\theta)}{r^2(\cos^2\theta +b\sin^2\theta)} \\
&=\frac{1+a + (1-a)\cos 2\theta}{1+b+(1-b)\cos 2\theta}.
\end{align*}
$$

For $S_1$, I think $|y| < c|x|^p$ "forces" $\theta \to 0$ as $(x,y)\to 0$. So $\cos 2\theta \to 1$ and $f(x,y) \to 1$.

For $S_2$, $\theta$ could be anything in $[-\pi, -\pi+\pi/4) \cup (-\pi/4,\pi/4) \cup (\pi -\pi/4, \pi)$. So the limit does not exist.

How can I make these rigorous?

Thank you!

Comment: No, $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ does not force $\theta \to 0$, even for $|y|<c|x|^p$. Go to zero along the $y=cx/2$ line, for instance. What you've shown is that the limit depends on which angle you approach the origin from. This implies that the limit doesn't exist (think of left and right hand limits in single variable calculus).

Comment: You're right; $\theta$ could cluster around $\pm \pi$ as well. In any case, $\cos 2\theta$ clusters around $\pm 1$ and $f(x,y)\to 1$ in $S_2$. The y-axis is not in $S_2$ nor $S_1$ though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2+ay^2}{x^2+by^2}$$  I don't think polar coordinates help.

For starters, the limit of $f(x,0)$ as $x\to 0$ is then $1$, so if the limit of $f$ exists for $(x,y)\to (0,0)$, it must be $1$.

For case 1, $|y|<c|x|^p=o(x)$ (i.e., $|y|$ goes to zero faster than $x$) in $S_1$. We have also $ay^2=o(x^2)$ and $by^2=o(x^2)$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$, so the limit of $f$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ is $$\lim_{x\to 0} {x^2+o(x^2)\over x^2+o(x^2)} = 1$$ as desired.

For case 2, let's suppose $y=x/c$, $c>1$, so that the line $y=x/c$ lies within $S_2$.  We then have $x^2+ay^2=x^2(1+a/c^2)$ and likewise $x^2+by^2=x^2(1+b/c^2)$ so the value of $f$ on the line $y=x/c$ is $(1+a/c^2)/(1+b/c^2)$.  Since $c>1$ is arbitrary, the value of $f$ on different lines in $S_2$ passing through the origin is different, and so the limit of $f$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ doesn't exist.